# Generate HTML tooltip based on url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

i dont know how can i achieve this.

Lets say i have a url like this:

```
site.com/stuffs/stuffexample1

site.com/stuffs/stuffexample2
```

Now i want to generate tooltips from links  using data from the links above.

In other words ill have a text in the blog (site.com/blog/somepost) that contain one of the links, i want to load a html from a div inside the /stuff/* wich is hidden by default, like a preview of the link.

I've tried using this plugin but not sure how to implement it.
http://jquerytools.github.io/demos/tooltip/any-html.html

**Edit:**
According to documentation the plugin work like this

```
<a id="download_now">Download now</a>

<!-- tooltip element -->
<div class="tooltip">

  <img src="/media/img/title/eye.png" alt="Flying screens"
       style="float:left; margin:0 15px 20px 0" />

  <table style="margin:0">
    <tr>
      <td class="label">File</td>
      <td>flowplayer-3.2.7.zip</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Version</td>
      <td>2011-03-03</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Size</td>
      <td>112 kB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">OS</td>
      <td>all</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <a href="/release-notes">What's new in 3.2</a>
</div>
```

And the Jquery call

```
  $("#download_now").tooltip({ effect: 'slide'});
```

But i dont want to load a element inside the same page, i want to load from another page, see?

Comment: Could you provide some code indicating what you have tried? Thanks.

Comment: ill edit the question, but not sure if the pugin i linkd is the best one ok, thats my question